# AS400 Telnet Emulator Auto Login

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a TN5250 emulator from sourceforge : http://sourceforge.net/projects/tn5250/ and I am trying to enable automatic login via the instructions I found here : http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2877.html

The string that I am sending is basically the following (I am aware that this is being passed as cleartext and I am not sure if passing it encrypted is necessary):
"\u0000USER\u0001"+user+"\u0003IBMRSEED\u0001\u0003IBMSUBSPW\u0001"+pass

The method I call pads the beginning of the string with the following hex characters:
FF FA 27 00 00

The same method mentioned above also pads the end of the string with the following hex characters:
FF F0

FYI: I haven't been receiving a response from the server that says WONT NEW-ENVIRON

Unfortunately I am not automatically logging into the AS400 and I don't know enough about the AS400 to know why. Thus the first question I would like to ask is how would I determine that this method is failing/working?

The next question is: Is there anything that I am doing obviously wrong?

Any other bits of criticism and advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Section 4.7 in the [HOWTO](http://www.chowhouse.com/~james/tn5250-HOWTO.pdf) explains the way to automate logins.

**EDIT:** Broken link, text pasted here.

```
4.7 Automatic login
You can configure tn5250 to automatically log in to the iSeries using the env.USER, env.IBMSUBSPW,
env.IBMPROGRAM, env.IBMIMENU, and env.IBMCURLIB arguments. If you wanted to automatically log in as
user MYUSER with password MYPASSWORD you would set these arguments like this:
env.USER = MYUSER
and
env.IBMSUBSPW = MYPASSWORD
The env.IBMPROGRAM, env.IBMIMENU, and env.IBMCURLIB arguments refer to the respective signon fields for
program, menu, and current library. These have the same syntax as env.USER and env.IBMSUBSPW. Adding
these to our .tn5250rc file results in:
as400 {
host = as400.mydomain.com
env.TERM = IBM-3477-FC
env.DEVNAME = MYDISPLAY
+underscores
map = 37
env.USER = MYUSER
env.IBMSUBSPW = MYPASSWORD
env.IBMPROGRAM = MYPROGRAM
env.IBMMENU = MYMENU
env.IBMCURLIB = MYLIBRARY
}
```

**EDIT 2** Pasted full text at the [Midrange wiki](http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/Tn5250).